# How to use dictionary output when using MirroredStrategy in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a framework on top of tensorflow that can train models in a generic way (there's more to it but that's not relevant for the question).
User will need to specify his `compute_loss` function which should return a dictionary loss name -> loss value. Even though models are optimised on one loss, this is to keep track of eventual intermediary losses, essentially for logging.

```
def compute_loss(**data_dict, **predictions):
   # compute some losses
   return { 'total_loss': total_loss, 'intermediary_loss1': intermediary_loss1 }
```

The `total_loss` key has to exists and it references the loss used for optimisation.

Then I define a generic `train_step`:

```
    def train_step(data_dict):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = model(**data_dict, training=True)
            loss_dict = compute_loss(**data_dict, **predictions)

        total_loss = loss_dict['total_loss']
        gradients = tape.gradient(total_loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
        return loss_dict
```

However when using using `MirroredStrategy` for multi-gpu training, I need to wrap the `train_step` as so (from TF doc):

```
@tf.function
def distributed_train_step(dist_inputs):
  per_replica_losses = mirrored_strategy.run(train_step, args=(dist_inputs,))
  return mirrored_strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, per_replica_losses,
                         axis=None)
```

I need to apply a reduce to aggregate losses over replicas, but how can I apply a reduce operation if my train step returns a dict?

The underlying question behind this is how and where in the code can I keep track of losses name and values at the same time after execution of a train step.

Thanks